# Intellij - View Git commits before pull

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm using Intellij new version with GitToolBox plugin

Before pushing to remove repository I must pull first,

But sometimes pulling break compilation, so I want to check the commits before pulling

Is there an option to view git commits before pulling them?

I'm working on a project that isn't stable where multiple users are committing changes before checks

Comment: `git fetch` will update remote references.

Comment: What exactly do you want to view/compare here?

Comment: If the pulls conflict with your code, don't you get merge errors to resolve?

Comment: Do you need to check 1) the new commits to be pulled? or 2) what these new commits will produce when merged to yours? If 1, as @eftshift0 advised, `git fetch [--dry-run]` is the way indeed. But in case 2, you'll have to try the merge (optionally in a temp branch), because there's no conflicts preview.

Comment: @eftshift0 code committed may break compilation or behavior (working on a project that isn't stable where multiple users are committing changes before checks)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want to view that the changes aren't breaking existing code (working on a project that isn't stable where multiple users are committing changes before checks)

Comment: Then I suggest doing a git diff on each file of interest of your current branch against the branch to be pulled.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is a multi modules project, how can I know which files where changed before pull?

Comment: There is a Git command to show which files were changed in a given commit.